# On a website, is it possible to fill in fields of a form on another domain that doesn't use query string parameters?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, web, cookies

I have a website that links to a donation form on another domain's website.
Is there any possible way to fill in some of the fields of that form when the page loads on the other domain? (The other domain's website doesn't use query string parameters.)

I'm open to any suggestions using any kind of web frameworks and technologies to try to hack this together.
E.g. loading the donation website's form in an iframe, or cookie manipulation (though I'm pretty sure there's no path of success here since security features prevent anything applicable), or recreating the form on my website and targeting the same submission action that's on the donation website's form.

Comment: Nope. If the other site doesn't give you an explicit way to communicate those values to it, then you can't do it. And that's a good thing, as cross-domain scripting like that is a major security risk.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible. According to security restrictions, iframe also is not possible.

1. Unless you have clear API access to 3rd party website for your purposes, e.g they support query string parameters.
2. Hack: Create your own form and send data directly to the script used by donation form of that 3rd party website, unless they do not have csrf token protection.

P.S But anyway if they do not provide explicit way for you purposes - all approaches are not stable since their scripts/forms can be changed tomorrow and your implementation will be broken.

Comment: Easiest way to determine the script / submission action by the source code of the donation website? (I'm not seeing any kind of click or get/post events on the submission button.)

Comment: I would just do next: open the Chrome Dev Tools and check the "Network"  tab 
 and probably XHR subtab in this Network section. And check if there are new items appears when you click submit button. Anyway when you submit data on this website, they have to save this data on the server so server-side communication must be detected.